# Sparse Matrix Multiplication Sparsekit Fortran in R

Tags: r, matrix, fortran, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to write a subroutine for matrix sparse matrix multiplication in R using [Sparsekit](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/sparsekit/sparsekit.html). It is a simple Fortran subroutine that calls two subroutines in the Sparsekit

```
 subroutine mprod(nrowa,ncola,ncolb,job,ra,fa,ca,rb,fb,cb,rc,fc, cc, nnzc, iwi,err)
 call amubdg(nrowa,ncola,ncolb,fa,ca,fb,cb,ndegr,nnzc,iwi)
 call amub (nrowa,ncolb,job,ra,fa,ca,rb,fb,cb, rc,fc, cc, nnzc,iwi,err)
 return
 end
```

The subroutine `amubdg` gets the number of nonzero elements in each row of the product, i.e., it returns `nnzc` that I need to specify in `amub` to compute the product. Here comes my question, in `R` after compiling with no problem the function in the package I'm working on.

```
z <- .Fortran("mprod",
              nrowa=as.integer(nrowa),
              ncola=as.integer(ncola),
              ncolb=as.integer(ncolb),
              job= as.integer(1),
              ra=as.double(A.csr@ra),
              fa=as.integer(A.csr@ja),
              ca=as.integer(A.csr@ia),
              rb=as.double(B.csr@ra),
              fb=as.integer(B.csr@ja),
              cb=as.integer(B.csr@ia),
              rc=double(nnzc),
              fb=integer(nnzc),
              cb=integer(A.csr@ia+1),
              ndegr=integer(nrowa),
              iwi=integer(ncola),
              err=integer(1),
              PACKAGE = "naus")
```

The question is the following then, is there a way to call the subroutine from `R` without having to specify the size of the arrays that I want out? This is, a priori I don't know what `nnzc` is going to be, this is calculated by `amubdg`, but to call it from `R` I need it to specify it.  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.